# NSDecimalNumber round long numbers

Tags: numbers, nsnumberformatter, nsdecimalnumber

I'm trying to get NSDecimalNumber to print out large numbers, 15 or more digits.  At 15 digits I see 111,111,111,111,111.  Above 15 digits I see 1,111,111,111,111,110 even though the number being formatted is 1111111111111111.

An example to illustrate my problem:

```
NSNumberFormatter *formatter = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
[formatter setNumberStyle:NSNumberFormatterDecimalStyle];
[formatter setMaximumSignificantDigits:25];
[formatter setUsesSignificantDigits:true];

NSDecimalNumber* test = [NSDecimalNumber decimalNumberWithString:@"12345678901234567890"];

NSString* output = [formatter stringFromNumber:test]; 
NSLog( @"num value: %@", test ); 
NSLog( @"str value: %@", output );
```

And the output looks like:

```
2010-09-16 09:24:16.783 SimpleCalc[739:207] num value: 12345678901234567890
2010-09-16 09:24:16.784 SimpleCalc[739:207] str value: 12,345,678,901,234,600,000
```

What silly thing have I missed?

Answer (score 3):

The problem here is that `NSNumberFormatter` does not handle `NSDecimalNumbers` internally, they are converted to `double` and you are seeing the resulting loss in precision. From the docs:

> The representation encompasses integers, floats, and doubles; floats and doubles can be formatted to a specified decimal position.

You should probably be taking a look at the `- (NSString *)descriptionWithLocale:(NSDictionary *)locale` method on `NSDecimalNumber`.

Answer (score 1):

Or `NSDecimalString()`. Take your `NSDecimalNumber` (e.g. `myDecimalNumber`), extract the `NSDecimal` via `decimalValue` (`NSDecimal decimal = [myDecimalNumber decimalValue]`) and create an `NSString` with the `NSString *myString = NSDecimalString(decimal)` function.

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Miscellaneous/Foundation_Functions/index.html#//apple_ref/c/func/NSDecimalString