# Unexpected behaviour formatting very large decimal numbers in ObjC

Tags: objective-c

I am running into unexpected behaviour formatting very large numbers in ObjC using the NSNumberFormatter.

It seems that the number formatter rounds decimals (NSDecimalNumber) after the fifteenth digit regardless of fraction digits.

The below test fails on values 1,3 and 5.

Two requests:

- Any suggestions on alternative code would be greatly appreciated?
- I assume the issue is happening due to the usage of a hard-coded digit limit in NSNumberFormatter?

The post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9385783/ios-formatting-decimal-numbers) lists a workaround without sufficient description if the problem. Also our application (banking sector) runs across multiple countries and we link the formatting to the user's locale as configured in the backend. This workaround would imply that we write our own number formatter to handle the requirement. Something I do not want to do.

```
- (void)testFormatterUsingOnlySDK {
    NSDecimalNumber *value1 = [NSDecimalNumber decimalNumberWithMantissa: 9423372036854775808u exponent:-3 isNegative:YES];
    NSDecimalNumber *value2 = [NSDecimalNumber decimalNumberWithMantissa: 9999999999999990u exponent:-3 isNegative:YES];
    NSDecimalNumber *value3 = [NSDecimalNumber decimalNumberWithMantissa: 9999999999999991u exponent:-3 isNegative:YES];
    NSDecimalNumber *value4 = [NSDecimalNumber decimalNumberWithMantissa: 99999999999999900u exponent:-4 isNegative:YES];
    NSDecimalNumber *value5 = [NSDecimalNumber decimalNumberWithMantissa: 11111111111111110u exponent:-4 isNegative:YES];

    NSNumberFormatter *formatter = [[[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init] autorelease];
    formatter.allowsFloats = YES;
    formatter.maximumFractionDigits = 3;

    [self assertStringAreEqualWithActual:[formatter stringFromNumber:value1] andExpeted: @"-9423372036854775.808"];
    [self assertStringAreEqualWithActual:[formatter stringFromNumber:value2] andExpeted: @"-9999999999999.99"];
    [self assertStringAreEqualWithActual:[formatter stringFromNumber:value3] andExpeted: @"-9999999999999.991"];
    [self assertStringAreEqualWithActual:[formatter stringFromNumber:value4] andExpeted: @"-9999999999999.99"];
    [self assertStringAreEqualWithActual:[formatter stringFromNumber:value5] andExpeted: @"-1111111111111.111"];
}

- (void)assertStringAreEqualWithActual:(NSString *)actual andExpeted:(NSString *)expected {
    STAssertTrue([expected isEqualToString:actual], @"Expected %@ but got %@", expected, actual);
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately, `NSNumberFormatter` doesn't work correctly with `NSDecimalNumber`.
The problem (very probably) is that the first thing it does is calling `doubleValue` on the number it wants to format.

See also [NSDecimalNumber round long numbers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3727142/nsdecimalnumber-round-long-numbers)

After many tries with `NSNumberFormatter`, I have created my own formatter, it's actually very easy:

1. Handle `NaN`.
2. Round using `roundToScale:`
3. Get `stringValue`
4. Check if negative, remove leading `-`
5. Find decimal point (`.`)
6. Localize decimal point (`[locale objectForKey:NSLocaleDecimalSeparator]`)
7. Add grouping separators (`[locale objectForKey:NSLocaleGroupingSeparator]`)
8. If negative, add leading `-` or put the number into parenthesis if you are formatting currency.
9. Done.

Answer (score 1):

You should compile your own NSNumberFormatter from this open source code, changing the prefix. This should allow you to debug into the formatting and to understand why this is happening. Worst case you can submit a patch to Apple.

http://code.google.com/p/cocotron/source/browse/Foundation/NSNumberFormatter.m?r=7542c3a7ef0ef75479e6154a75d304113f5a9738

Comment: I doubt Apple will be able to do much with a patch to someone else's source code.

Comment: @cocoanetics. Thanks. That should give me insight into the cause of the issue

Comment: oh, I just noticed that this is a reverse-engineered version. Oh well, maybe it behaves the same then it can be debugged. If not, maybe it can used as a replacement.

Answer (score 1):

You've set `maximumFractionDigits` to two. All of the failing tests have three fraction digits in the expected value. Either the expectation or the code needs to change to match. If I make this change:

```
formatter.maximumFractionDigits = 3;
```

then all of your test cases are met.

Comment: my mistake. Issue still exists if maximumFractionDigits is 3.

Comment: That's not what I see. I've run the code you supplied and see no failures. What are the 'actual' values you observe?

Comment: @amok Could that be an SDK version problem?

Comment: @Sulthan Issue is happening on 4.3, 5.0 and 5.1. Also happening in simulator and physical devices. (Does not relate to the version of LLVM either, not that it should). I think I am going to go with your solution and use the link that Cocoanetics supplied as reference.

Comment: @GrahamLee thanks for trying to run on 6.0 it led to the solution and sorry if I wasted your time.