# How to stop rounding in NSDecimalNumber?

Tags: swift, foundation

I am solving a question from HackerRank which asks to print the value of extra-long factorials that can't be stored even in a 64-bit long variable.

I am using `NSDecimalNumber` to store the value. However, even in this case, the final result is rounded off.

```
func extraLongFactorials(n: Int) -> Void
{
    var factorial: NSDecimalNumber = 1
    for index in 1...n
    {
        let indexInNSDecimal = NSDecimalNumber(value: index)
        factorial = factorial.multiplying(by: indexInNSDecimal)
    }
    let factorialWithoutRounding = factorial.description(withLocale: nil)
    print(factorialWithoutRounding)
}

print(extraLongFactorials(n: 45)) // 119622220865480194561963161495657715064000000000000000000
```

However, the result should be `119622220865480194561963161495657715064383733760000000000`.

This link talks about using `description(withLocale:)`. 
[NSDecimalNumber round long numbers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3727142/nsdecimalnumber-round-long-numbers)

However, it does not clearly explain how to use the `description(withLocale:)` method. 
I also went through the apple doc https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsdecimalnumber/1412789-description. But it also does not explain clearly how to use it.

Can someone please discuss this method in detail.

Comment: The precision of NSDecimalNumber is limited to 38 decimal digits. That is not enough for your task.

Comment: @MartinR Is there any other way of saving numbers that require more than 38 digits of precision?

Comment: Have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43830151/swift-3-calculate-factorial-number-result-becomes-too-high and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25531914/biginteger-equivalent-in-swift