# How to format string to Decimal without losing precission?

Tags: ios, swift, floating-point

Lets take a look at this simple example

```
let formatter = NumberFormatter()
formatter.number(from: "0.945")?.decimalValue // result: 0.945
formatter.number(from: "0.94")?.decimalValue  // result: 0.9399999999999999
```

How can I achieve that `"0.94"` converts to Decimal with exact same value e.g. `0.94`?

I prefer solutions with `NumberFormatter` because I want to use this String to Decimal conversion also for amounts with currency, such as `"$0.94"` and `"0.94€"`

Comment: See [NSDecimalNumber round long numbers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3727142/nsdecimalnumber-round-long-numbers)

Answer (score 1):

[This website](https://floating-point-gui.de/basic/) contains explanation. Basically, computers store these numbers using a system that can't represent them very accurately.
If you need to have better accuracy, I suggesting working with decimal types such as `Decimal` or `NSDecimalNumber`:

```swift
Decimal(string: "0.945")
Decimal(string: "0.94")
```

Comment: Don't forget to mention that it only works if you use the string initializer. If you pass a float literal it may lose precision as well.

Comment: `Decimal(1234.999999999999)` would result in `1234.999999999998976` while using the string initializer `Decimal(string: "1234.999999999999")`  would result in `1234.999999999999`

Comment: The point is not to use float literals since they can't be stored with accuracy. It makes no sense to initialize a Decimal using a float literal if you want to achieve that accuracy, that precision error will just be passed into the Decimal value.

Comment: I know that but the OP probably doesn't. The same applies for future readers of this post.